# Кнопка проваливается вниз

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста. На мобильной версии сайта, eсли у товара добавлена плашка со скидкой то кнопка в Корзину проваливается вниз, как исправить эту ситуацию?
Этот слайдер с товарами на главной странице.

https://xn--e1aofbbhkdf.xn--p1ai/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за ссылка  ?

Comment: Эта ссылка на сайт